# Collate two collections using Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I am looking around for a tool to automate the collation of two collections into each other and I think Automapper should work for this.  We have many instances of this operation and I would like to centralize this logic into a single area.

I have the following two classes:

```
public class Product
{
    public IEnumerable<Order> CurrentCustomerOrders { get;set; }
}

public class Order
{
    order properties
}
```

And they are retrieved via the following calls:

```
_repo.GetTable<Product>();
_repo.GetTable<Order>().Where(n => n.CustomerId = _customerId);
```

What I want is to put all the Orders into the Products or something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IEnumerable<Order>, IEnumerable<Product>>()
  .ForEachMember(n => n.CurrentCustomerOrders), opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Where(Order.ProductId == Product.ProductId))
```

How would I go about doing this using Automapper?  Or do you know of a better tool to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would do the filtering first using Linq or something and then do the mapping. Automapper is just a mapping tool.

e.g.

```
Product.CurrentCustomerOrders = 
     Mapper.Map<OrderDO, Order>(Orders.Where(o => o.ProductId == Product.ProductId));
```